# Not able to connect to AmazonMQ via MQTT protocol using Python(paho.mqtt.python) library

Tags: python, activemq-classic, mqtt, paho, amazon-mq

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

USERNAME = "admin-user"
PASSWORD = "admin-user@12345"
AUTH = {"username":USERNAME, "password":PASSWORD}
HOSTNAME = "ssl://b-c7d1ea8g-f777-4c71-23a3-2d73088fdb64-1.mq.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
PORT = 8883
TOPICNAME = "paho/test/single"
PAYLOAD = "Hope Stackoverflow Help Me Resolve This Issue!"

publish.single(TOPICNAME, payload=PAYLOAD, hostname=HOSTNAME, port=PORT, auth=AUTH, protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311, transport="tcp", client_id="", keepalive=60, will=None) # This won't work
# publish.single(TOPICNAME, payload=PAYLOAD, hostname="localhost") # This works!

print('published message payload = ', PAYLOAD)
```

I am able to connect to AmazonMQ with Java eclipse Paho client, but not able to do same the in Python. It gives me an error "**gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known**".

The above python code works fine with a locally hosted ActiveMQ MQTT broker and also in stand alone server where I have hosted ActiveMQ MQTT broker. But the same is not working with AmazonMQ broker.

This issue is already mentioned in the issue tracker of [Github Paho](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/issues/372), but still there is no solution that will help.

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the "ssl://" from your host variable, and set a ssl context in order to connect to Amazon-MQ with paho.

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()
client.tls_set_context(context=context)
```

Here is a working version of the example posted on your github issue.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient

import time
import ssl

context = ssl.create_default_context()

Connected = False 
broker_address= "b-xxxxxx-acbf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" # No ssl://
port = 8883
user = "xxxxxx"
password = "xxxxx"

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):

    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to broker")
        global Connected                #Use global variable
        Connected = True                #Signal connection  
        client.subscribe("test/data")
    else:
        print("Connection failed")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

client = mqttClient.Client("Test") #create new instance
client.username_pw_set(user, password=password) #set username and password
client.on_connect=on_connect
client.on_message=on_message
client.tls_set_context(context=context)
client.connect(broker_address, port=port)
client.loop_start()

while Connected != True:
    time.sleep(0.1)

client.publish("test/data", "This is my test msg 123.")
time.sleep(10)
```